# Adding a row to be the header of a table created to convert a CSV to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, csv

Hello i would like to add a static row that is bolded to serve as the header of the table generated from the script below, i don't want to put the headers on the csv file but on the html file itself in that way the header its always unchanged.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"employee.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need at add a static header html element to your function before you start looping in the data.

Something like:

```
var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
   </tr>';
```